# Azure DevOps error 'Git fetch failed with exit code 1: could not read Username

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a Git repo on Azure DevOps and I am trying to fetch the origin/main branch. However, the command failed with Bash existed code 128.

> fatal: could not read Username for 'https://xxx.xxx.com': terminal
> prompts disabled
> ##[error]Bash exited with code '128'.

This is my release pipeline definition:

```
# Release pipeline

pr: none
trigger: none

variables:
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

pool:
  vmImage: $(vmImageName)

jobs:
  - job: release
    workspace:
      clean: all
    steps:
      # Install Node
      - task: NodeTool@0
        inputs:
          versionSpec: '16.14.x'
        displayName: 'Use node 16.14.x'

      # Authenticate private VivaCommonUX feed packages
      - task: npmAuthenticate@0
        displayName: 'npm Authenticate .npmrc'
        inputs:
          workingFile: .npmrc

      # Install Yarn package manager
      - task: geeklearningio.gl-vsts-tasks-yarn.yarn-installer-task.YarnInstaller@3
        inputs:
          versionSpec: '1.22.x'
        displayName: 'Use Yarn 1.22.x'

      # Check Node, NPM, Yarn version
      - script: |
          echo "Node Version: "
          node -v
          echo "NPM Version: "
          npm -v
          echoe "Yarn Version: "
          yarn -v
        displayName: 'Check Node, NPM, Yarn version'

      - script: |
          git fetch -- origin main
        displayName: 'fetch origin main'
```

The reason why I did `git fetch -- origin main` is to debug the [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/beachball/issues/674). It performs a `git fetch -- origin main` under the hood.

Any reason why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out an additional step is required for the pipeline have access to the system token. More information to enable git command in Azure DevOps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

Add a `checkout` session with `persistCredentials` set to true.

```
steps:
  - checkout: self
    persistCredentials: true
```